# Dell Precision M4800 Drops LAN connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan, wired-networking

I have a Dell Precision M4800 - my problem is that the LAN disconnects sporadically. I know that if I have WiFi on it defaults to that even if the LAN cable is plugged in. I've installed all the latest drivers as well as the latest BIOS. I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

What I've tried so far other than updating everything is to disable all wireless comms and use the LAN cable alone but only orange lights flash, it tries to connect for a few seconds then drops the connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - the slower speeds on the WiFi are driving me insane!

Comment: When it drops what message do you get? Does it say the cable is unplugged, it's an unidentified network, or another message?

Comment: It says network cable unplugged, wireless disabled.

Comment: The port and cable are both in good condition? Have you tried another cable to be sure?

Comment: I've tried another cable, and I tried different ports on a few desks and it does the same thing every time.

Comment: Now what it does is connect for a while then for no reason disconnect. No error message - then it tries to reconnect within seconds of disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reinstalling Windows 7 from scratch with fresh drivers and the latest BIOS. Now by default it allows both LAN and WiFi connections to run simultaneously and it will switch between whichever is offering the best connection. Not the most precise solution but nuking it and starting afresh is a last resort worth entertaining for those that are in the same boat.